# Aggregation of daily futures prices to quarterly prices

Tags: dataset, finance, aggregation

We are working to incorporate the EIA future prices into our quarterly data set of financial balance sheet data. There are four different contracts, which are available at the [EIA website](https://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/pet_pri_fut_s1_d.htm).
The idea is that instead of spot prices, we are using the prices of the future contracts as a more forward-looking price time-series.

Initially, we just aggregated per contract and month and then averaged the three resulting values again for the complete quarter.

```
2019 - Q1 - January - Avg. of 1-Month-Ahead Contract 
2019 - Q1 - February - Avg. of 1-Month-Ahead Contract 
2019 - Q1 - March - Avg. of 1-Month-Ahead Contract
```

I am pretty sure this is not optimal, since two of the values only look forward into the same quarter.
Therefore, I am looking for better or established empirical ways to aggregate the futures data to a quarterly value. The available contracts are the respective forwards for 1 to 4 months ahead.

Comment: I just found the Alquist & Kilian (2010) (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jae.1159) paper and they are describing a way to construct monthly values from daily future prices. I will try to write up an answer, when transferring it to the next higher aggregation level.